# Error in the installation of phpmyadmin of xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, failed-installation

i have installed mysqlserver version-5.5with following specifications:
   `-->username:system

    -->password:system`
      port was given as 3306 at the time of installation.No problem here and it works fine.
After thet i have installed xampp version-1.7.3. after insatallation completed, xampp control panel opened with mysql service started by default and the check box against mysql service was checked by default as shown in this video[Click on this link and see the video from 3:37 minuits][1]

[1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gH1i7o6i52I. and apache service working well. But my problem is when i open localhost/phpmyadmin it shows an error like

```
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'.
```

I don't know why is this happening. please provide any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the security settings?

localhost/security

localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php

If you have looked at this, did you change the connection string in the website you are creating?  From what you described, it is the authentication in the website you made that is failing.